# In mutt, how can I easily attach files which contain spaces in their name?

Tags: mutt

I'd like to attach some files in mutt's compose screen. I press <kbd>a</kbd> to attach. However, if I paste in a path with spaces, it eats the spaces up. Similarly, if I drag and drop a GUI icon into my terminal, it will similarly eat up the spaces.

Invariably, I mess around a few times, then manually type out (with tab-complete) the entire path. How can I easily attach files from within mutt?

Comment: Mutt doesn't have that feature but you can try this 

`mutt -s "subject" $( printf -- '-a %q ' *.csv )` hope it works

Comment: Thanks @Mongrel. Using `-a` is probably the best option AFAIK, but means I have to remember that I'm attaching before I compose… and doesn't help for adding more attachments later, or if I change my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the key bindings of the line editor prompt to make <kbd>Space</kbd> insert a space. By default, it invokes `buffy-cycle`, which cycles through completion possibilities or offers a completion menu. You can rebind this to another key, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (I think mutt can't handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> which the terminal transmits as a null byte).

```
macro editor <space> "\Cv "
bind editor \e\  buffy-cycle
```

As far as I know, you can't have different key bindings for different kinds of prompts. You can change key bindings dynamically by calling `bind` in hooks, but I don't think there's a hook that runs at the right time.

Alternatively (or in addition), you can define a macro in the compose menu that attaches a file whose name is in the clipboard.

```
macro compose \Ca "<attach-file>`xsel -b | sed "s/ /$(printf \\026)&/g"`<enter>"
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! Just out of interest (I've never used it), what exactly do you mean with `buffy-cycle`? I searched but couldn't find any lucid information. It seems to be different from tab-completion (e.g. when attaching or changing mailboxes), right? Also, what's the purpose of the second line (`bind editor…`)?

Comment: @Sparhawk `buffy-cycle` is the name of the command that <Space> is bound to. That command normally cycles through folders with new mail (as opposed to Tab which completes anything), I don't actually know what it does when it's opening a file that isn't a mailbox. The second line binds it to Alt+Space.

Comment: Doesn't `next-unread-mailbox` do the same thing then? I'm also not sure when it works… i.e. what is the `editor` mode exactly? (Thanks for the explanation of the second line, I was parsing it as `\e\\` originally.)

Comment: @Sparhawk No: `next-unread-mailbox` switches to a mailbox, `buffy-cycle` pops up the mailbox name and does not quit the line editor.